# Blazor WASM support multiple versions

Tags: blazor, version, webassembly

In a .Net 8 Blazor WASM app, I would like to support multiple versions as follows:

- Customers who always want the latest automatic updates: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- Customers who want automatic updates but stable/less frequent changes: [www.example.com/lts](http://www.example.com/lts)
- Customers who want to stay with a specific version until they choose to upgrade: [www.example.com/1.0](http://www.example.com/1.0), [www.example.com/2.0](http://www.example.com/2.0), etc.

I'd like to always deploy to a physical folder on web server with deployed version #... and then virtually redirect the root path and the lts path to the appropriate folder in IIS config.

I realize that any apis and services the WASM app use (separately hosted) and any local storage will have to be forward and backward compatible... but I am mainly asking if this folder structure/IIS/Blazor config is possible... AND, if the browser will properly handle loading newer/older modules if a user jumps around to different versions.

OR, if there is an entirely better way to handle this case where some customers will want always latest without any second thought, and others will want specific version until they coordinate an update.

Trying to decide best way to test this.